# Re-expressing an ODE in terms of it's independent variable

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose I have that $y = F(x)$ with the knowledge that $F^{-1}$ is also a smooth function. Consider the differential equation

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + y'^2}} \frac{d}{dx} (\frac{y'}{\sqrt{1 + y'^2}} )= 0$$

How can I re-express this as a differential equation where $x$ depends on $y$?

Comment: Solve for $y$ invert the equation and then take a derivative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y'=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{\frac{dx}{dy}}=\frac{1}{x'}$$

substitute
$$
\frac{y'}{\sqrt{1 + y'^2}}=\frac{1/x'}{\sqrt{1+1/x'^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x'^2}}
$$
and
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + y'^2}} \frac{d}{dx} (\frac{y'}{\sqrt{1 + y'^2}} )= 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + 1/x'^2}} \frac{d}{dy} {\sqrt{1 + 1/x'^2}} 
$$

Answer (score 2):

Your equation says that
$${d\over dx}\left({y'\over\sqrt{1+y'^2}}\right)=0\ ,$$
which implies that $x\mapsto y'(x)$ is a constant, or that $$y(x)=Ax+B$$
for constants $A$, $B$. Assuming $A\ne0$ we can solve for $x$:
$$x(y)=Cy +D\ ,$$
and the simplest ODE encoding this is $\ddot x=0$, whereby the dot denotes differentiation with respect to $y$.